Trying to understand behavior of Fortran compiler
This toy code has a problem.  The program needs an explicit interface for the subroutine print_i.
module types

type plain
  integer :: i
end type plain

type, extends(plain) :: fancy
  integer :: i2
end type fancy

end module



program poly

use types

!  UH-OH!  Missing interface!

type(plain) :: pl
type(fancy) :: fan

pl%i = 10
fan%i = 20

call print_i(pl)
call print_i(fan)

end program


subroutine print_i(instr)
use types
class(plain) :: instr
print '("i is ",i5)', instr%i
end subroutine

When I try to compile with GNU Fortran, it won't compile, and gfortran complains about the missing interface.  What is strange to my mind is that Intel Fortran compiles an executable without complaining, but then it dies with a seg fault in print_i.  When I put the interface in ...
interface
  subroutine print_i(instr)
    use types
    class(plain) :: instr
  end subroutine
end interface

both compilers compile without error and their executables run fine.
The Intel behavior seems strange to me.  Why not flag something that can't run?  Any ideas?
(BTW, I understand that I can put print_i into the module and have simpler code.  But this came up because of something I am trying to test.)

Please edit the question to show the exact compilation lines you used. Compiler versions might be useful as well. But given compilers by default compile something that is not quite standard fortran, and all compilers differ in how not quite, its likely Intel is by default accepting something gnu doesn't. Also off the top of my head I can't tell you if a compiler is required to diagnose this.

Have you nicely asked the compiler to check your code (-warn interfaces, perhaps)? Do you get just as confused when a compiler compiles dimension x(1); x(4578)=45.75; end but then crashes when running?

When using external functions, you are responsible for calling them properly. They could be in some library, procompiled code, wherever. They might be written in a different programming language or directly in assembly. The compiler cannot check everything. When they happen to be in the same Fortran source file, then the compiler can do some checks, but it is not required to do. It certainly helps if you enable all optional warnings and checks the compiler offers.

Indeed, if the main routine is written in (say) main.f90 and the remaining "library" codes are written in mylib.f90, then "gfortran mylib.f90 and main.f90" gives segfault w/o warning at compile time (after commenting out "print_i(pl)")...

Subroutine print_i(instr) has a polymorphic parameter instr. So it needs an interface.
If it wasn't polymorphic there would be no problem.
For the record:

gfortran with no specified options told me the error and didn't compile

ifort with no specified otions compiled without demur and gave the expected answer when run on one occasion and crashed on another!
ifort /warn test.f90


correctly identified that you need an interface here (because the argument is polymorphic).

nagfor ... just couldn't cope with a procedure being called with different types of arguments and didn't compile.

All compilers work fine if you include an interface for print_i, either with an explicit interface block in the calling program or by putting the procedure into the types module.
For polymorphic types ... use an interface.
